# Resolve "none is not an allower value"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am currently trying to write an application in which one object (Room) inherits from the other (Building). But when I try to create a room using the Swagger API (create Room) I get the following error:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Room
response -> content
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed).
```

I have only recently started with SQL and Python and am having a hard time solving this problem. I would be very happy about help and a possible explanation of what I am doing wrong.

Here is my Code:

models.py:

```
class Building(_database.Base):
    __tablename__ = "buildings"
    id = _sql.Column(_sql.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = _sql.Column(_sql.String, index=True)
    date_created = _sql.Column(_sql.DateTime, default=_dt.datetime.utcnow)
    date_last_updated = _sql.Column(_sql.DateTime, default=_dt.datetime.utcnow)

    rooms = _orm.relationship("Room", back_populates="owner")


class Room(_database.Base):
    __tablename__ = "rooms"
    id = _sql.Column(_sql.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = _sql.Column(_sql.String, index=True)
    content = _sql.Column(_sql.String, index=True)
    owner_id = _sql.Column(_sql.Integer, _sql.ForeignKey("buildings.id"))
    building_title = _sql.Column(_sql.String, index=True)
    date_created = _sql.Column(_sql.DateTime, default=_dt.datetime.utcnow)
    date_last_updated = _sql.Column(_sql.DateTime, default=_dt.datetime.utcnow)

    owner = _orm.relationship("Building", back_populates="rooms")
```

schemas.py:

```
    #Rooms
class _RoomBase(_pydantic.BaseModel):
    title: str
    content: str


class RoomCreate(_RoomBase):
    pass


class RoomUpdate(_RoomBase):
    pass


class Room(_RoomBase):
    id: int
    owner_id: int
    building_title: str
    date_created: _dt.datetime
    date_last_updated: _dt.datetime

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


#Buildings
class _BuildingBase(_pydantic.BaseModel):
    title: str


class BuildingCreate(_BuildingBase):
    pass


class BuildingUpdate(_BuildingBase):
    pass


class Building(_BuildingBase):
    id: int
    date_created: _dt.datetime
    date_last_updated: _dt.datetime

    rooms: List[Room] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

services.py

```
#Buildings
def create_building(db: _orm.Session, building: _schemas.BuildingCreate):
    building = _models.Building(title=building.title)
    db.add(building)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(building)
    return building

def get_building(db: _orm.Session, building_id: int ):
    return db.query(_models.Building).filter(_models.Building.id == building_id).first()

def get_building_by_title(db: _orm.Session, building_title: str ):
    return db.query(_models.Building).filter(_models.Building.title == building_title).first()

def delete_building(db: _orm.Session, building_id: int):
    db.query(_models.Building).filter(_models.Building.id == building_id).delete()
    db.commit()


def update_building(db: _orm.Session, building_id: int, building: _schemas.BuildingCreate):
    db_building = get_building(db=db, building_id=building_id)
    db_building.title = building.title
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_building)
    return db_building

#Rooms
def create_room(db: _orm.Session, room: _schemas.RoomCreate, building_id:int, building_title: str):
    room = _models.Room(title=room.title,owner_id=building_id, building_title=building_title)
    db.add(room)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(room)
    return room
```

main.py

```
#Building
@app.post("/buildings/", response_model=_schemas.Building)
def create_building(
    building: _schemas.BuildingCreate, db: _orm.Session = _fastapi.Depends(_services.get_db)
):
    return _services.create_building(db=db, building=building)

@app.get("/buildings/{building_id}", response_model=_schemas.Building)
def read_building(building_id: int, db: _orm.Session = _fastapi.Depends(_services.get_db)):
    building = _services.get_building(db=db, building_id=building_id)
    if building is None:
        raise _fastapi.HTTPException(
            status_code=404, detail="sorry this building does not exist"
        )

    return building

@app.delete("/buildings/{building_id}")
def delete_building(building_id: int, db: _orm.Session = _fastapi.Depends(_services.get_db)):
    _services.delete_building(db=db, building_id=building_id)
    return {"message": f"successfully deleted building with id: {building_id}"}


@app.put("/buildings/{building_id}", response_model=_schemas.Building)
def update_building(
    building_id: int,
    building: _schemas.BuildingCreate,
    db: _orm.Session = _fastapi.Depends(_services.get_db),
):
    return _services.update_building(db=db, building=building, building_id=building_id)



#Room
@app.post("/rooms/", response_model=_schemas.Room)
def create_room(
    building_title: str,
    room: _schemas.RoomCreate,
    db: _orm.Session = _fastapi.Depends(_services.get_db),
):
    db_building = _services.get_building_by_title(db=db, building_title=building_title)
    if db_building is None:
        raise _fastapi.HTTPException(
            status_code=404, detail="sorry this building does not exist"
        )
    return _services.create_room(db=db, room=room,building_id=db_building.id, building_title=db_building.title)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're returning a Room that has `None` as the value for `content` - since you didn't include which endpoint this is and what your request is, it's hard to say exactly what triggers it - but if `content` can be `None` (or NULL in your database), you'll have to define the field as `Optional` by wrapping the type `content: Optional[str]` - Optional can be imported from `typing`.

Comment: thank you very much, at least i now know what triggers the problem, but I'm not sure as well what the problem is. Content should be filled out and not be none.

Comment: Not sure if i understand this right, but the Endpoint should be create_room ?

Comment: The room you're creating doesn't have a value for `content`, but you have not defined it as being optional (so it needs to be present and not `None` accoring to your response schema for `Room`): `room = _models.Room(title=room.title,owner_id=building_id, building_title=building_title)` - `content` isn't mentioned anywhere, but you have it as a field in your response model.

Answer (score 1):

As MatsLindh points out, `RoomCreate` has a `content` field that is not used in `services.create_room`. Simply changing to

```py
def create_room(db: _orm.Session, room: _schemas.RoomCreate, building_id:int, building_title: str):
    room = _models.Room(title=room.title, content=room.content, owner_id=building_id, building_title=building_title)
```

If `content` is required, you should probably also define your SQLAlchemy model as `content = _sql.Column(_sql.String, nullable=False, index=True)`.

For next time, please learn how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)